# How to split multiline string to array

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I use this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

parser = BeautifulSoup(remote_data)
parse_data = parser.find_all('a')
for atag_data in parse_data:
    URL_list = atag_data.get('href')
```

When i try to split URL_list to array:

```
array = str.split(URL_list)
```

I give this 3 arrays:

```
['index1.html']
['example.exe']
['document.doc']
```

But i need only one array like:

```
['index1.html','example.exe','document.doc']
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please add a sample of your input to your question.

Comment: Why are you trying to split -- again? it should already be a list (arrays are called lists in python).

Comment: Anyways, to split a string, you do ``yourstring.split(separator)``, that ``str.split(yourlist)`` doesn't make much sense to me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get an array - its a list!
Also, you should avoid naming variables like builtins.

Regarding your question:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
parser = BeautifulSoup(remote_data)
link_list = [a['href'] for a in parser.find_all('a')]
```

Comment: What do you mean by `you should avoid naming variables like builtins`? I don't see any instances of that in his code.

Comment: @Matt: You should not name a variable "array", "dict", "list" etc. I meant the line `array = str.split(URL_list)`.

Comment: @sphere Okay, thats what I thought you may have meant, but why not array? array isnt a python builtin.

Comment: Okay - you are right, "array" is not a builtin, but there is an [array-object available](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html)